# Qual a diferença de SCHEMA e DATABASE?

Tags: mysql, sql, terminologia

Eu nunca tinha usado o MySQL Workbench e ele ao invés de database, me dá a opção de SCHEMA. Qual a diferença dos dois? Dá no mesmo um ou outro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

> **schema** Conceptually, a schema is a set of interrelated database objects, such as tables, table columns, data types of the columns,
>   indexes, foreign keys, and so on. These objects are connected through
>   SQL syntax, because the columns make up the tables, the foreign keys
>   refer to tables and columns, and so on. Ideally, they are also
>   connected logically, working together as part of a unified application
>   or flexible framework. For example, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and
>   performance_schema databases use “schema” in their names to emphasize
>   the close relationships between the tables and columns they contain.
>
> In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. You can
>   substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax,
>   for example using CREATE SCHEMA instead of CREATE DATABASE.

Em tradução livre:

> Conceitualmente, um schema é um conjunto de objetos de banco de dados
>   inter-relacionados, como tabelas, colunas, tipos de dados, índices,
>   chaves estrangeiras e assim por diante. Esses objetos estão conectados
>   através de sintaxe SQL, porque as colunas compõe as tabelas, chaves
>   estrangeiras referenciam essas columas, e assim por diante. Idealmente
>   eles também estão conectados logicamente, trabalhando juntos como
>   parte de um aplicativo unificado ou estrutura flexível. Por exemplo,
>   os bancos de dados INFORMATION_SCHEMA e performance_schema usam
>   "schema" em seus nomes para enfatizar os relacionamentos próximos
>   entre as tabelas e colunas que eles contêm.
>
> No MySQL, fisicamente, um esquema é sinônimo de um banco de dados.
>   Você pode substituir a palavra-chave SCHEMA por DATABASE na sintaxe
>   SQL do MySQL, por exemplo, utilizando CREATE SCHEMA no lugar de CREATE
>   DATABASE.

Ou seja, podemos entender que um *schema* é um banco de dados.
Apenas para referências, em outros bancos de dados o conceito de *schema* pode ser ligeiramente diferente (em Oracle por exemplo um *schema* é um conjunto de tabelas e outros objetos, enquanto um banco de dados é mais amplo, possuindo um conjunto de *schemas*).

Answer (score 6):

No MySQL são sinônimos.

Segundo a documentação do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

> *In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. You can substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax, for example using CREATE SCHEMA instead of CREATE DATABASE.*
>
> *Some other database products draw a distinction. For example, in the Oracle Database product, a schema represents only a part of a database: the tables and other objects owned by a single user.*

Traduzindo:

> No MySQL, fisicamente, um "schema" é sinônimo de um banco de dados. Você pode substituir a palavra-chave SCHEMA em vez de DATABASE na sintaxe SQL do MySQL, por exemplo, utilizando CREATE SCHEMA em vez de CREATE DATABASE.
>
> Alguns outros produtos de banco de dados fazem uma distinção. Por exemplo, no produto Oracle Database, um esquema representa apenas uma parte de um banco de dados: as tabelas e outros objetos pertencentes a um único usuário.