# Existe definição canônica para esquema (schema) de banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, schema

Cada banco parece definir esquema (*schema*) de uma maneira diferente.

Veja por exemplo o [MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316045/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-schema-e-database), o [MS SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21031/357), o [PostgreSQL](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceito-de-schema-no-postgresql/1532)...

Existe uma definição canônica relevante ou têm importância somente as definições individuais?

Comment: Acho que o mais próximo a isso é a definição de *schema* no ISO/IEC 9075. Infelizmente você tem que pagar para obter uma cópia desse documento (eu não poderia linkar nada aqui). Dito isso, não li nada na especificação que resolva definitivamente o impasse sobre qual é a implementação mais "correta" de *schema*. Ainda que, ao menos para um leigo em *design de databases* como eu, o PostgreSQL e o SQLServer aparentem seguir o padrão mais de perto.

Comment: Há uma forma padronizada de se consultar as informações dos esquemas, denominada `INFORMATION SCHEMA`. Vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei dizer, não sou especialista no assunto e não circulo em meios acadêmicos que usam melhor esse tipo de informação, mas eu [começaria pela Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema). Não que ela seja sempre confiável, mas é sempre um bom começo para achar o que deseja. Depois de confirmada, pode ser que a informação ali seja resumidamente canônica.

Você tem razão que cada SGDB usa do jeito que interpreta, por isso é aquela coisa, pode até haver algo canônico, mas de que adianta se essa forma não é seguida na prática? Por isso na prática a definição de cada passou ser mais importante. Para quem quer ser especialista em banco de dados deveria saber bem a canônica também, ainda que por caber interpretação, isso pode não ser exatamente possível. Ter sua própria interpretação bem fundamentada pode até ser mais importante que ter algo canônico.